# Side-Loaded Windows Runtime Application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, windows-runtime

I'm developing a LOB application that will be side-loaded to Windows 8.1 Pro systems. I had setup my environment around [Brokered Windows Runtime Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx) to allow Metro Application consume my Data Access Layer based in Entity Framework 6.
Everything compiles fine but at runtime I get: *The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception*.

Error message: 
*Writeable performance counters are not allowed when running in AppContainer.*

My DbContext class is very straightforward:

```
public class LOBContext: DbContext
{
    public LOBContext():base(Properties.Settings.Default.NorthwindConnectionString){}

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Map(p => p.ToTable("Employees"));                
    }
}
```

I know about the isolation stuff for AppContainer, but precisely the goal of Brokered Runtime Component was supposed to be marshaling all this interprocess comunication requiered to use legacy components written in .net managed code. So why am I getting this exception and what can be a workaround here?

EDIT:Additional information

Package.appxmanifest file:

```
 <Extensions>
            <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
                <InProcessServer>
                    <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
                    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="BrokeredRT.DataStub" ThreadingModel="MTA">
                        <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" 
    Value="c:\InstalledBrokeredComponents\" />
                    </ActivatableClass>
                  </InProcessServer>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
```

[image]

Comment: Lots of moving parts to this, a simple mistake is hard to diagnose and there are plenty to make.  From the sound of it you didn't partition the code properly, the EF code must execute in the desktop-side server.

Comment: @HansPassant, that make a lot of sense, can you point me (sample code or link ) how setup up EF to execute in the desktop-side server? I have followed all instructions carefully and I am running out of options by now.

Comment: @Fran_gg7, I gave up with this as I realized that the best approach for Windows Runtime Applications to consume database is through WCF Data Service or Web Api. I'm going with Web Api because it seems that will have more support in the future.